# Post to facebook page using fb api from client

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am trying to post to a users page . This is how far i have come , I get userId and userToken from FB.getLoginStatus and then post to my feed using this code . Now I want to post to a page but i keep getting you dont have permission to post to a page.

```
  FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
                           message:'This is my message',
                           link:"http://trello.com",
                            name: 'This is my message',
                            description: 'This is my message'
                        },function(data) {
                           console.log(data);
                            alert(data);
                       });
                        },
                     { scope: "publish_actions" });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong endpoint , you have to use '/pageid/feed'. After getting the userid and token you need to get all the pages he has permission for by hitting the '/me/accounts' . Now you get the pageid of page you want to post from here and then hit '/pageid/feed' to post . 
Here is some code:

```
FB.login(function(responses1) {
                        FB.api('/me/accounts', 'get',function(data) {
                        //you will get a list here.......//for now i am hardcoding it to the first page
                            var page_access_token = data.data[0].access_token;
                            var pageId = data.data[0].id;
                            //now post to the page
                            var target = '/'+pageId+'/feed'

                            FB.api(target,
                                'post',
                                { message: "message",
                                    link: "link",
                                    picture: "",
                                    caption: "",
                                    description: "",
                                    name: "",
                                    access_token: page_access_token
                                }
                                ,function(response) {
                                    if (!response || response.error) {
                                        console.log("in error");
                                       console.log(response.error);
                                    } else {
                                        console.log(response);
                                    }
                                });
                                    });
                    }, { scope: "manage_pages,publish_pages" });
```

Also you need to change scope to :

```
manage_pages,publish_pages
```

Comment: you don´t need publish_actions for pages. that permission is only needed for posting as user (on pages or the own user profile).

Comment: Though it does not explain properly but this snippet solved my issue , thanks for the quick reply

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing some things up. Permissions need to be asked for with `FB.login`, not when using the API:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user is logged in
    }
}, {scope: 'publish_actions', return_scopes: true});
```

After authorization, you can use the API:

```
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', {
        message: 'This is my message',
        link: 'http://trello.com',
        name: 'This is my message',
        description: 'This is my message'
    }, function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```

More information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

That´s for the user profile. Posting to a Page (as Page) needs the `manage_pages` and `publish_pages` permissions:

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        //user is logged in
    }
}, {scope: 'manage_pages,publish_pages', return_scopes: true});
```

You have to get a Page Token for your Page with this API call after authorizing: `/{page-id}?fields=access_token`:

```
FB.api('/' + pageId + '', {fields: 'access_token'}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

After that, you can use the Token in the response to post as Page.

```
FB.api('/' + pageId + '/feed', 'post', {message: 'some message', access_token: pageToken}, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

**Side Note: Prefilling the message and autoposting (right after login) is not allowed, make sure you read the platform policy before creating any App: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/**